# Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$, and let $x$ be in the conjugacy class $A$ of $G$. Show that $\frac{|C_G(x)||A\cap H|}{|H|}$ is an integer.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Question: Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$, and let $x$ be in the conjugacy class $A$ of $G$.  Show that $\frac{|C_G(x)||A\cap H|}{|H|}$ is an integer.

My thoughts: We know that $|A|=|cl_G(x)|=|G:C_G(x)|$.  Since we want an "$|A\cap H|$" term in the numerator, it makes me think that we need to play with $AH$ (how do we even know this is a subgroup?).  So, we would have that $|AH|=\frac{|A||H|}{|A\cap H|}=\frac{\frac{|G|}{|C_G(x)|}|H|}{|A\cap H|}$, so I suppose I could then say that $|AH|\frac{|C_G(x)||A\cap H|}{|H|}=|G|$, and since $|G|$ is an integer, then so is the LHS, but that doesn't necessarily mean that both $|AH|$, and the part that we want, are both integers... any help is greatly apprecaited!  Thank you.

Comment: Something doesn't seem right. What do you mean by, "let $x$ be in *the* conjugacy class $A$"?

Comment: OP just calls this conjugacy class $A$. You can give a name to any subset of $G$, right?

Comment: @Mark, yes, that is what I mean.  Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$A \cap H$ is a union of conjugacy classes of $H$, let $h_1,\ldots,h_k$ be  representatives of these classes.

So $|A \cap H|$ is the sum of the sizes $|H|/|C_H(h_i)|$ of these classes, hence $|A \cap H|/|H| = \sum_{i=1}^k 1/|C_H(h_i)|$.

But $|C_H(h_i)|$ divides $|C_G(h_i)| = |C_G(x)|$.

Comment: How do we know that $A\cap H$ is a union of conjugacy classes of $H$?  I know that $A$ is a conjugacy class of $G$, so if we intersect it with $H$ then we have the elements of the conjugacy class that are just in $H$, but how do we know that it is still a conjugacy class... I feel like this should be obvious, but it also feels like something that some trivial counterexample could break..

Comment: @user7238: If something is conjugate to $x$ in $H$, then it is conjugate to $x$ in $G$. So the elements of $H$ that lie in the same conjugacy class in $G$ will split into a (disjoint) union of conjugacy classes in $H$ (because they may fail to be conjugate in $H$ even though they are conjugate in $G$). But you cannot end up with elements that are conjugate in $H$ to something in $A$ and are not also in $A$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I see, thank you! 

Last thing... the second line, could you rephrase that a bit?  It makes sense in my head, but I just can't see why on paper (if that makes sense)

Comment: @user7238: If $x\in A\cap H$ and $y$ is conjugate to $x$ in $H$, then $y$ is conjugate to $x$ in $G$ so $y\in A$. Thus, if $x\in A$, then the entire $H$-conjugacy class of $x$ is also contained in $A$.

Comment: Perfect, thank you, I really appreciate it!